# tomcat 8 as windows service

Tags: java, tomcat

I have installed Tomcat as a Windows service and I can see it in Windows Service section of my computer. I followed the stems as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

I want to perform the following step now :

`Running Tomcat as Windows Service (enables default STDOUT logging): To configure choose from your windows Start menu ->Programs->Apache Tomcat8  -> Configure Tomcat
In Tomcat Properties, choose Java tab, and add this to Java Options:
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n`

However, I couldn't find Apache Tomcat8 listed on my Program menu. Does anyone know where I need to go from here?

Comment: Have you tried `http://localhost:8080/manager/html` from the server or PC you've installed Tomcat 8 on from a web browser on that machine by chance? You might see if you can find a file in the Tomcat 8 install directories, etc. named `tomcat8w.exe` and launch that to see if it brings up the properties to configure through a GUI non-web interface too. Start by checking in the `~\bin` folder or subfolders, etc.

Comment: @LMFAO_A_JOKE No. I haven't.  I am unable to log into the Tomcat Manager even after entering the username and password as `tomcat` as mentioned in `tomcat-users` file in conf directory.

Comment: Were you able to locate a file named `tomcat8w.exe` to launch the properties options?

Comment: Take a look here [Tomcat8 How To Manager](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html) it may have something to do with the roles or needing to setup a NEW account with the role as talked about there . . .

Comment: . . On that link where it say... `To enable access to the Manager web application, you must either create a new username/password combination and associate one of the manager-** roles with it, or add a manager-** role to some existing username/password combination. As the majority of this document describes the commands of plain textual interface, let the role name for further example to be manager-script. Exactly how the usernames/passwords are configured depends on which Realm implementation you are using:`

Comment: That link has some good detail about Tomcat 8 . . . It also states `You can find the role names in the web.xml file of the Manager web application. The available roles are:` and beneath there are the names of the roles and what they allow so start with that and see if that helps you any... I'll keep my fingers crossed!!

Comment: @LMFAO_A_JOKE Thanks, I did find `tomcat8w.exe` to launch the properties option but eventually ended up installing the Apache Tomcat as a service.

Comment: I thought you were running Apache Tomcat 8 as a Windows Service and that's what you were having trouble with. In any event, I'm glad you solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1) Open a command prompt, go to the bin folder of the apache tomcat and run "service.bat install". If the CATALINA_HOME, JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME are correctly configured, the 'Tomcat' service will be installed successfully.

2) Go to Services, and look for Apache Tomcat service. Update the startup type to "Automatic" and click on "Start", then "OK".